# Why is there no warning like C4738 for double?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, compiler-warnings

Visual C++ can emit [C4738 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c24hdbz6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> storing 32-bit float result in memory, possible loss of performance

for cases when a 32-bit `float` is about to be stored in memory instead of being stored in a register.

The description further says using `double` resolves the issue. I don't get why the latter is true.

Why is storing `float` in memory result in performance loss and storing `double` does not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning combines two issues:

- Floats need to be stored in memory rather than registers, which can reduce performance (because memory is much slower than registers)
- Floats will be rounded (because registers have 64 or 80 bits always, but in memory a float only has 32 bits).

Using double resolves the second issue (at least partially, 64 bits are still less precise than 80 bits), but has no impact on the possible performance loss. Which is why the warning decription mentions TWO remedies:

> To resolve this warning and avoid rounding, compile with /fp:fast or
>   use doubles instead of floats.
>
> To resolve this warning and avoid running out of registers, change the
>   order of computation and modify your use of inlining

Comment: Why would `float` result in performance loss, but not `double`?

Comment: @tenfour: *both* will result in performance loss, but the double will not be rounded as much.

Comment: @tenfour:  When you stash a 64-bit floating point register in a 32-bit memory location, you have to round, and the rounding takes time.  When you stash a 64-bit floating point register into a 64-bit memory location, you don't need to round, just store.  (Most floating points is now down with SSE registers, so the 80-bit stuff is _usually_ irrelevant.)

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy: Hm - do you really think the rounding itself will be more performance-relevant than the memory access? I guess it depends on the details of the architecture in any case.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: it might be relevant in that it takes up execution units that could otherwise be used on other instructions

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: In both cases, you have to pay the performance cost of storing in memory.  In the float cast, you _also_ have to round, which is an additional performance hit.  That's my understanding anyway.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not 100% sure of the cause, here's my guess.

When compiling on x86 and SSE2 is not enabled, the compiler must use the x87 FP stack for all floating-point registers. On MSVC, the FP-mode, by default, set to the 53-bit precision rounding. (I think. I'm not 100% sure on this.)

Therefore, all operations done on the FP-stack is at double-precision.

However, when something is cast down to a `float`, the precision needs to be rounded to single-precision. The only way to do this is to store it to memory via the `fstp` instruction over a 4-byte memory operand - and reload it.

---

Let's look at the example on the [C4738 warning page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c24hdbz6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you linked to:

```
float func(float f)
{
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    extern float f, f1, f2;
    double d = 0.0;

    f1 = func(d);
    f2 = (float) d;
    f = f1 + f2;   // C4738
    printf_s("%f\n", f);
}
```

When you call `func()`, `d` is probably stored in an x87 register. However, the call to `func()` requires that the precision be lowered to single-precision. This will cause `d` to be rounded/stored to memory. Then reloaded and re-promoted to double-precision on the line `f = f1 + f2;`.

However, if you use `double` the whole way, the compiler can keep `d` in register - thus bypassing the overhead of going to and from memory.

---

As for why it could make you run out of registers... I have no idea. It's possible that the semantics of the program may result in having both double-precision and single-precision values of the same value - which, in this case, require an extra register.

Comment: Is this still relevant for SSE2+ vectorized instruction sets? I guess there you can round directly in registers.